# Change logo on specific page id using css

Tags: css

I am trying to change the logo one specific page of this wordpress site. http://staging-domesticbliss.transitiongraphics.co.uk/db-home-help/

Currently I know I am targeting the right page and element as I can hide the logo using:

```
.page-id-6935 .w-logo-img > img {
     display:none;
}
```

But how do I now show the logo located at http://staging-domesticbliss.transitiongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/db-homehelp-black-xl.png

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using the  tag in html, set the logo using the CSS background property. Use background-image:url(http://staging-domesticbliss.transitiongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/db-homehelp-black-xl.png); instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
.page-id-6935 img.for_default {
   content: url(/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/db-homehelp-black-xl.png);
}
```

Using content replaces the logo, whereas background image puts the new logo behind the original.

Comment: Yes, that will do it, but keep in mind this selector is only good as long as the page id does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Logo settings are controlled through the WordPress customizer and administrator interface for most themes today. This site is using the Impreza theme; [see the documentation for its logo settings](https://help.us-themes.com/impreza/options/logo-options/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm aware of the logo options, but they are still site wide. I wish to change the logo on one single page.

Comment: In that case, use the CSS method given by Megh. You can target the relevant logo selector on a specific page with most themes today. If there is not a unique ID or class for the page you'll have to add one via your child theme.